# Help как реализовать?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Есть форма, нужно чтобы при вводе в поле "text123" он передавался в http://test.xyz/order/text123
Тобишь чтобы там где идет /order/* , выставлялось значение введенное в форме, как это реализовать?

Comment: менять `action` формы на `change` у поля ввода

Answer (score 0):

Можно на лету менять `action` формы на событие `change` у поля ввода

```js
document.getElementById('var').addEventListener('change', function(){
  document.getElementById('form').action = `https://httpbin.org/post/${this.value}`;
});
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(){
  // Ничего никуда не отправляем, просто перепроверяем action
  this.res.value = this.action;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://httpbin.org/post/example">
  <input id="var" value="example"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Go"><hr/>
  <input name="res" value="result">
</form>
```

Сниппет не работает из-за запрещённого `allow-forms` в песочнице, посмотреть можно в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2vtu1vs/)